# How to make full backup?

Tags: backup, 9.0-pie

My phone is a Nokia 6.1. I'd like to do a factory reset, but preserving:

- my personal files
- the settings of all apps
- the data saved by all apps (e.g. the alarms saved by the stock Clock app)
- the collection of apps (I want them to be reinstalled after the reset)

Does the "Settings -> Advanced -> Backup" Android feature do all that? If no, then what part does it do?

Comment: And no, Google backup doesn't cover all. Especially when you consider restore.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2819582?hl=en):

```
If you back up to Google Drive, here's what's backed up:

Google Contacts data
Google Calendar events and settings
Wi-Fi networks and passwords
Wallpapers
Gmail settings
Apps
Display settings (brightness and sleep)
Language and input settings
Date and time
Settings and data for apps not made by Google (varies by app)
Note: Not all apps can back up or restore all settings and data. To find out about an app, learn how to contact its developer.
```